# How do I center the div vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

```
.title_text_only{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
display:none;
z-index:9;
top:50%;
bottom:50%;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
font-size:18px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;
}
```

Right now, it doesn't seem to work. top 50% doesn't center it vertically. It's a little to the bottom.  It's as if the top border is 50%.

Comment: try first adding an arbitrary height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can specify the height of the box, you can use `margin-top: -[height / 2]px` (fill in `[height / 2]` and note that most browsers will round fractional pixels up at 100% zoom).

If you can specify the height of its parent, you can do something like this:

```
parent {
    height: [height]px;
}
child {
    /* Make the element part of the inline flow, as vertical-align isn't supported on block elements */
    display: -moz-inline-box; /* Old Firefox doesn't support inline-block */
    display: inline-block;
    /* IE < 8 doesn't support inline-block on native block-level elements */
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;

    /* The interesting bit */
    line-height: [height]px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If the content of the child is expected to wrap onto multiple lines, you can wrap it in a sub-child that resets the `line-height`.

Answer (score 2):

[How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

`top: 50%;` does exactly what you suspect: it places the top *edge* at 50% height. You can offset this effect by also applying a negative vertical margin equal to half of the height of the element. For example, if the element was 100px high, you would add this property:

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

Answer (score 1):

If height of element is fixed, then do following

Css:

```
.title_text_only{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
display:none;
z-index:9;
**top:50%;**
bottom:50%;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
font-size:18px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;
**margin-top: -(half the height)**
}
```

else to vertically center a div with dynamic height, you would need javascript..

```
document.getElementById('myElement').style.marginTop = (-1) * document.getElementById('myElement').offsetHeight / 2
```